# How to use richtext box for maintain text formating?

Tags: mysql, types, richtextbox, varchar

I am creating such application where user can post there articles up to `800-1000 words`.

What should I use to maintain text formatting like paragraph, next line etc.(if I use `textarea` as input textbox for article?). I am using `mySql` so what shod my `datatype` to store article text **VARCHAR** or **TEXT**?? and what should be the `size` for 1000 words?

Answer (score 1):

With VARCHAR you can store up to 65000 bytes. If you need more, you'll need to move to MEDIUMTEXT (16 million bytes).
For utf8 you should calculate two bytes per character.

You don't need to do anything special to preserve line breaks when storing data to MySQL. You need however process these linebreaks into adequate html tags `<br>` when pulling the data from database for displaying. Gor example PHP has `nl2br()` function.